# How to properly texture sculpted model

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, image

I am trying to texture this model, But I didn't retopologize it because I found that a bit difficult.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: This is what it currently looks like]

I put him in some armor:

[image: I put him in some armor]

I made an attempt to texture him here:

[image: I made an attempt to texture him here]

This [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33532) is a previous save because the current file is too big, What am I going wrong?

Mesh:

[image: Mesh edit mode]

How would you texture him without artifacts?

Comment: By the looks of it you arent texturing it , just applying a material...

Comment: Hello thanks for replying, i am new to blender and don't really know much, how would i begin to give him skin so he looks more like a rhino man?

Comment: i added some links , one of them have a rhino man texturing

Comment: What method of sculpting did you use? You may need to do some retopology for UV unwrapping to be practical.

Comment: Thanks Knuckles i will have a look, and i used a bit of dyno and normal sculpting. unfortunately my first try at retopology came out having problems

Comment: Would you say that is something i definitely have to do? There were problems building my base mesh which i didn't know how to fix, if you look at this earlier version, whenever i went down subdivision levels it just went all weird and i think that's what happened to the retopology. Please have a look http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33543

Comment: Well if you want it to be like a statue , you can just apply a material , after doing a smart UV project and it would like fine , but texturing can make it flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to know the basics of UV unwrapping .

UV unwrapping

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2-FfB9kRmE

You also need to know how to texture , You dont need to texture it , you can also use materials but it isnt the best idea if you arent using it only for rendering :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thYHF0282cE

Also be sure to look at lots of references and watch how other people do it :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3r2T7xU9Kw

there is also Clone painting , Shown in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4ngVoGIj1Q

And since you are beginner you might want to take a look at  basic texturing :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwpwzHPtqMc

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged as if the linked site goes down so does this answer. Please provide at least some of the steps to answer the question within the answer itself.